# How to compute the eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix of n-order wheel graph?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This matrix looks like this.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots& \vdots \\   
        1 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
On every row and every column,there are three "1".Diagnoal entries are 0.I already know that
the eigenvalues are $1+\sqrt{n+1},1-\sqrt{n+1},\{2\cos (\frac{2(m-1)\pi}{n})\}_{2\le m\le n}$.
How to compute the corresponding eigenvectors?

Comment: The ones for the cosine eigenvalues are just the $j=2,\dots n$ columns of the matrix $[\zeta^{(i-1(j-1)}]_{i,j}$ where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$, with an extra $0$ tagged on at the foot. The other two are orthogonal to these, and must be easy to find? (I started knowing the eigenvectors of the big top left block.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm sorry but your format seem to have some problem.You mean that the eigenvalues I provided is wrong?Maybe,I get these numbers on a book..

Comment: No, I am saying that apart from the $1\pm\sqrt{n+1}$ eigenvalues you just use the columns of the $[\zeta^{(i-1)(j-1)}]_{i,j}$ matrix, but stick a zero at the foot to make them the right size, and these will give you eigenvectors for the $\zeta^j+\zeta^{-j}=2\cos 2\pi j/n $ eigenvalues.